# How to set up Apache mod_rewrite to hide file path which is a value of one parameter and do not change the other URL params?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please, could you help me with correct setting of rewrite rules in Apache virtual.host.conf?

I have corect output on url

`http://qgis.demo:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/katastry/katastry.qgs&LAYERS=SPH_OBEC&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:5514&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400&BBOX=-904585.2800000000279397,-1227295.8300000000745058,-431724.2999999999883585,-935236.9500000000698492`

After seting up

`ProxyPass /qgisserver http://qgis.demo:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe connectiontimeout=30 Timeout=30 KeepAlive=On`

I have the same corect output on url

`http://qgis.demo:8080/qgisserver?MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/katastry/katastry.qgs&LAYERS=SPH_OBEC&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:5514&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400&BBOX=-904585.2800000000279397,-1227295.8300000000745058,-431724.2999999999883585,-935236.9500000000698492`

I need to hide this full path to project file in URL `c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/katastry/katastry.qgs` via setting a rewrite rule. My goal is, to see the same output on url like

`http://qgis.demo:8080/qgisserver?MAP=katastry&LAYERS=SPH_OBEC&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:5514&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=400&BBOX=-904585.2800000000279397,-1227295.8300000000745058,-431724.2999999999883585,-935236.9500000000698492%60`

I'm trying to set up rewrite rules like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)MAP=(katastry)([&?].*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.*)$ $1?%1MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/katastry/katastry.qgs$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and a lot of diferrent modifications of it, but nothing seems to work. (I'm testing it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/)

What is the right definition, please?

And would not be usefull to try this using RewriteMap in case to work with more MAPs (MAP=katastry, MAP=m1, MAP=m2, .... ? All of those MAPs must have its own project like c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/m1/m1.qgs etc.)

Comment: With this definition in qgis.demo.conf
'''
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^MAP=katastry(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/katastry/katastry.qgs%1 [R=301,NC,L]
'''
I can see correct output in browser. But the "whole path" in address. How to keep 'MAP=katastry' in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

My solution I'm satisfied with:

```
ProxyPass /qgisserver http://qgis.demo:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe connectiontimeout=30 Timeout=30 KeepAlive=On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^MAP=([^&]+)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?rw=1&MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/%1/%1.qgs%2 [L,P]
# without rw=1 not functional - because of endless cycle

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?&MAP=c:/OSGEO4W/apps/qgis/bin/projects/%1/%1.qgs%2 [END,P]
# [END,P] The 'END' Flag is the solution without rw=1&.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).